# Why am I getting this error "bcrypt_lib.node is not a valid Win32 application. " while trying to run bcrypt?

Tags: node.js, express, bcrypt

I am building a fill stack app with node and express, I installed bcrypt and after trying to starting up the server, i get this error:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1189
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                 ^

Error: \\?\C:\Users\anjan\Desktop\web-projects\v_school\lvl6\rtv\backend\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\napi-v3\bcrypt_lib.node is not a valid Win32 application.        
\\?\C:\Users\anjan\Desktop\web-projects\v_school\lvl6\rtv\backend\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\napi-v3\bcrypt_lib.node
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1189:18)    
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\anjan\Desktop\web-projects\v_school\lvl6\rtv\backend\node_modules\bcrypt\bcrypt.js:6:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)      
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12) {
  code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}
```

I've tried:

- running npm rebuild bcrypt --build-from-source
- npm install node-pre-gyp -g then npm rebuild bcrypt --build-from-source
- deleting node_modules and package-lock.json
- deleting bcrypt out of node_modules and running `npm i`

I seen that Bcryptjs was not reccomended because it hasnt been updates in years.

Answer (score -2):

The error message you are seeing suggests that there is a problem with the bcrypt_lib.node file, which is likely related to the architecture of the file.

The most common cause of this error is trying to load a 32-bit version of the bcrypt library on a 64-bit version of Windows or vice versa. The architecture of the library must match the architecture of the operating system you are running it on.

To fix this error, you can try downloading the correct version of the bcrypt library for your system's architecture, or you can try recompiling the library from source code to generate a version that matches your system's architecture.

You may also want to check if your system is up to date with the latest updates and service packs, as this can sometimes cause problems with loading libraries.

The best answer is to avoid all of these native host system dependency issues and instead use docker and docker-compose. Run a linux image with your code on it guaranteed to work forever.

Portability: Docker allows developers to package their applications and dependencies into containers, which are portable and can run on any platform that supports Docker. This means that developers can easily move their applications from one environment to another without worrying about dependencies, configuration, or other compatibility issues.

Consistency: With Docker, developers can ensure that their applications will run consistently across different environments, including development, testing, staging, and production. This helps to reduce the risk of bugs or other issues that may arise from differences between environments.

Isolation: Docker containers provide a level of isolation between applications and their dependencies. This means that different versions of the same application or dependencies can coexist on the same system without conflict.

Efficiency: Docker containers are lightweight and can be spun up and torn down quickly, making it easy to test, deploy, and scale applications. This helps to improve developer productivity and reduce the time required to bring new features to market.

Collaboration: Docker makes it easy for developers to share their applications with others, either within their own organization or with the wider community. By sharing containers, developers can collaborate on projects, share best practices, and accelerate development cycles.

Overall, Docker is an amazing developer tool because it simplifies the process of building, testing, and deploying applications, while also improving portability, consistency, isolation, efficiency, and collaboration.

Comment: I took this and ran `npm install bcrypt --target_arch=x64` to try to get the 64-bit version after uninstalling and re-installng node_modules, but I just get the same error.

Comment: Whar is your node arch? node -p "process.arch"

Comment: Its x64, thanks for helping me find that.